# GKE certificate failing to read the secret created

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager, ingress-controller

my application is working on the given IP address as shown in the Services and Ingress section of Kubernetes Engine. i was able to create certificate and secret but message i am getting is secret does not exists. i have certificate.yaml, issuer.yaml,
ingress-service.yaml file
my certificate.yaml file

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1

kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: foodipes-com
spec:
  secretName: foodipes-com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  dnsNames:
    - foodipes.com
    - www.foodipes.com
```

issuer.yaml file is as

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: "easwardsharma@gmail.com"
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

my ingress-service.yaml file is as

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: 'letsencrypt-prod'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - foodipes.com
        - www.foodipes.com
      secretName: foodipes-com
  rules:
    - host: foodipes.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

for `kubectl get secrets` i got

```
NAME                                 TYPE                 DATA   AGE
foodipes-com-5r2l6                   Opaque               1      7h8m
```

i observed some 5 characters are always appending to secret being created by certificate.yaml. i even tried to change the secretName in ingress-service.yaml but still getting same error.
for `kubectl get certificates` i am getting

```
NAME               READY   SECRET         AGE
foodipes-com       False   foodipes-com   19h
```

so certificate is  made and expecting a secret but failing to find secret?
when i do `kubectl describe certificate foodipes-com` in cloudshell i am getting

```
Name:         foodipes-com
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-09-26T18:23:34Z
  Generation:          7
  Resource Version:    9748900
  UID:                 e19dbd6a-f50a-4ca5-c03256588e02
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    foodipes.com
    www.foodipes.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-prod
  Secret Name:  foodipes-com
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2023-09-26T18:23:34Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
    Last Transition Time:        2023-09-26T18:23:34Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         7
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  foodipes-com-5r2l6
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                       Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                       -------
  Normal  Requested  39m   cert-manager-certificates-request-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "foodipes-com-vlg9m"
```

please help me figure this out

I have installed helm and for the installation of cert-manager I did

```
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io 
helm repo update
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.8.0 \
  --set installCRDs=true
```

Comment: are you sure that secret is created? can you find the secret with `kubectl get secret -A` command? 

is resources are in same namespaces? it will help if you provide output of
`kubectl get -A certificate,secrets,ingress,ClusterIssuer`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DNS `foodipes.com` is pointing towards the correct IP address. Currently, when running `dig A foodipes.com`, you get three different IP addresses. Only the Load Balancer linked to the application's service should be added as an A record.

Once this is done, you can check whether routing and ingress rules are correct by making a request without HTTPS. If you get a successful response, then all is good. If not, the certificate will not be able to generate, because something is wrong with your routing.